# my messeging Desktop application does't work on wpf c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

So Basically I'm working on this Desktop application using c# server and client and for some reason whenever I send a msg in chat it doesn't work for all users but when I send a private msg it's working and I'm not sure why.

my server code:

```
 if (e.MessageString.Contains("#"))
            {
            if (e.MessageString.Substring(0, 3).Equals("All"))
            {
                if (!e.MessageString.Substring(4, 4).Equals("File"))
                {
                    
                    string toAll = e.MessageString.Substring(4, e.MessageString.Length - 4) + "\n";
                    server.Broadcast(toAll);

                    txtStatus.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate ()
                    {
                        txtStatus.Text += toAll;

                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Cannot send a file to everyone!");
                }
            }
```

and this is my chat code:

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Send was clicked");
        if (btnConnect.IsEnabled)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Please connect to the local server!");
        }
        else if (listbox.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            if (txtMessage.Text.Length > 0 && !ifFileSelected && !txtMessage.Text.Equals(" ") && !txtMessage.Text.Equals("\n"))
            {
                client.WriteLine(listbox.SelectedItem.ToString().ToLower() + "#" + username + ": " + txtMessage.Text);
            }
            else if (ifFileSelected)
            {
                byte[] b1 = File.ReadAllBytes(op.FileName);
                client.Write(listbox.SelectedItem.ToString() + "#File#" + fi.Name + "#");
                client.Write(b1);
                ifFileSelected = false;
            }
            else
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Please type something or choose a file to send!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Please select someone to send the message to!");
        }

        txtMessage.Text = "";
        
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Edit your question with the code of Broadcast method. Does the code just fail silently or is there an error? Put a breakpoint inside it and run it step by step

Comment: for some reason I get another error which is index out of range in some other parts of the code

Comment: `private Socket findSocket(string user, List<ClientDetails> list)
        {
            Socket userSocket;
            int counter = 0;

            foreach(ClientDetails details in list)
            {
                if (details.getUsername().Equals(user)) break;
                counter++;
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine(counter);
            ClientDetails resSock = list.ElementAt(counter);
            userSocket = resSock.getSocket();

            return userSocket;
        }`

Comment: Edit your question, don't paste them in the comment. And if you encounter an error, point out which line throw it and what are the details of the error, the variable values etc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2022